# Yii2 - subdomain - htaccess not working

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

I created sub-domain and am working using yii2 framework. `.htaccess` in subdomain not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
   RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
###Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting `RewriteBase` correct your issue. So change your htaccess to this and test:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /path/to/folder # <- Add this line to your htaccess
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css)
   RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
   RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css)/
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
###Deny accessing dot files
RewriteRule (^\.|/\.) - [F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```